# Подсчитать количество наиболее часто встречающегося слова в тексте

Tags: python, строки

Задача (на Python):
необходимо найти самое часто встречающееся слово в романе "Война и Мир" без учета:
пунктуации, слов короче четырех символов, 'Стоп-слов', которые приведены в файле в stop_words_russian.txt
Слово нашел, проблема в том, как изменить код, чтобы вывести количество этого слова.

```
import string

with open('war_and_peace.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()
    
with open('stop_words_russian.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    stop_words = f.read().split()
    
for p in string.punctuation:
    text = text.replace(p, '')
    words = text.split()
    words = [word for word in words if len(word) >= 4 and word not in stop_words]
    word_count = {}
    
for word in words:
    if word in word_count:
        word_count[word] += 1
    else:
        word_count[word] = 1

most_common_word = max(word_count, key = word_count.get)

print('Самое часто встречающееся слово в романе "Война и мир": ', most_common_word)
print('Количество слов: ', )
```

Comment: Если вы код сами писали , то это не должно быть проблемой. Значение лежит в словаре word_count по ключу most_common_word

Comment: Благодарю, @MBo
Всего то и нужно было `print('Встречается: ', word_count[most_common_word], 'раз')`